# Android package name of calling application - Chrome vs Google App

Tags: android

I want to be able to send the users back to the calling app after I am done with my app. But in this one case, I am not able to infer the calling app.

I am getting the calling application package by calling `getReferrer()` in my initial activity. I get the same package `com.google.chrome` when the users deeplink from the Chrome app and from the Google App (via the search box on the home screen). How do I distinguish between these two apps? It's clearly different apps when I open the recent apps drawer (see image)[image]

This is breaking my flow because I record Chrome as the calling app when the user comes in from the Google App, my redirect takes the user back to Chrome and not to the Google App. How do I distinguish between these two apps?

Comment: Note that there is no requirement for `getReferrer()` to return accurate results.

Comment: in that case, how can I make sure to take the user back to the calling app?

Comment: There is no guarantee that it is possible. After all, there is no guarantee that the calling app exists anymore. Simply `finish()` your activity, and Android will take you to the natural place for the user to return to.